# Formula fields to display Current time based on Company Information

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime, timezone, locale

Formula field to display current time based on the Company's default time zone, does anybody have the idea how to achieve this

For **User's timeZone** current time used the `NOW()` - but don't know how to find for **company's Time Zone**

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the default Org Timezone is not available in the `$Organization.xxx` merge fields. Nor, incidentally, is it available on the [Organization Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm?search_text=organization)

Thus, to make this available to formulas, you will need to use a hierarchical custom setting field `Default_Org_TZ__c` , set its value at the org-level in the UI editor so all running users will always have this value available.

Then you'll need to compare the running user's TZ offset versus the custom setting value and adjust `NOW()` accordingly. See [tip](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000suLPQAY)